# KiCad - Bus width indicator

Tags: schematics, kicad

How do you indicate the width of a bus in KiCad? Is there an equivalent to the "slash accompanied by a number" symbol typically used?

For example, as used in [this image](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs333/labs_f06/lab3/src.datapath.jpg):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KiCad, the bus width is given by the `[]` square bracket numbers.  The bus name `ADR[0..15]` denotes a bus with 16 members `ADR0` through `ADR15`.

Details are given in [KiCad Eeschema documentation](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/stable/en/eeschema.html#bus-members).